# Why does my external javascript file keep getting reloaded?

Tags: javascript

I have a jqGrid displaying Tabular data. I have a qTip2 popup window displaying a small window when a user mouses over a hyperlink inside the grid. I'm noticing that an external javascript file is being reloaded every time this popup window displays information.  The script is not referenced in the file that is called to display this popup window and would be loaded for the display of the main page.

I see the file being reloaded over and over with this kind of call:

```
GET http://localhost:4111/Scripts/HelperScript.js?_=1359649163699
GET http://localhost:4111/Scripts/HelperScript.js?_=1359649165768
```

and so on...

Can someone put me on the path of why this is happening?

Comment: That looks like a `$.getScript()` call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I just double checked and for some reason I had a call in the code that was being loaded to present the popup window that would also reference my script file.

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/HelperScript.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

I"m assuming since it was trying to load two copies of the same Javascript file that it was loading it again with a random name so as not to conflict?  (Removing the above reference from my code has stopped the script from being loaded again)

Comment: The random number is a "cache buster", to prevent reloading the file from cache. My guess is it's being added by the framework you're using.